# 2 different exception generated by doing minor change

Tags: c#, exception

I was playing with stackalloc and it throws`overflow exception` when I wrote below piece of code:-

```
var test = 0x40000000;
        unsafe
        {              
            int* result = stackalloc int[test];
            result[0] = 5;
         }
```

and when I make changes in test variable as shown below it throws `stack overflow exception`.

```
 var test = 0x30000000;
            unsafe
            {              
                int* result = stackalloc int[test];
                result[0] = 5;
             }
```

what is happening in both scenario??

Comment: I want to know what is happening in both scenario @TimSchmelter

Comment: the second one crashes Linqpad :)

Comment: Both arrays are larger than the largest allowed size of a single object in .NET (which is 2GB regardless of the platform). Additionally, default stack size for a thread is 1MB IIRC, so I am sure that using `stackalloc` for anything larger than that will also fail.

Comment: The wierd part is that you get two different exceptions. (Both StackOverflow on my machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime tries to calculate how much space is needed to store your array, and the first array is too large for the result to fit in the range of the type used.

The first array needs 0x40000000 * 4 = 0x0100000000 bytes of storage, while the second one needs only 0xc0000000 bytes.

Tweaking the array size and the array type (e.g. `long[]` or `char[]`) indicates that whenever the required space for the array goes over 0xffffffff you get the `OverflowException`; otherwise, the runtime attempts to create the array and crashes.

Based on the above I think it's fairly safe to conclude that the required space is being calculated using a value of type `uint` in a `checked` context. If the calculation overflows you unsurprisingly get the `OverflowException`; otherwise the runtime blows up due to the invalid unsafe operation.

Answer (score 1):

Both arrays are larger than the largest allowed size of a single object in .NET (which is 2GB regardless of the platform), meaning that this would fail even if you didn't try to allocate in on the stack.

In the first case, you need `4 * 0x40000000` bytes (`int` is 32-bit in .NET), which doesn't even fit inside 32-bits and creates an arithmetic overflow. The second case needs ~3GB but is still way larger than the 2GB limit.

Additionally, since you're trying to allocate on the stack, you need to know that the stack size for a single thread is ~1MB by default, so using stackalloc for anything larger than that will also fail.

For example, this will also throw a `StackOverflowException`:

```
unsafe
{
    byte* result = stackalloc byte[1024 * 1024];
    result[0] = 5;
}
```

Comment: Note that, due to memory fragmentation, the largest object you can typically allocate on the heap is often smaller than 2GB (a contiguous block of more than 1GB can be hardly found in a 32-bit app).